# Create user using Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

How do I create a user using Microsoft graph? For I am having issues with regards to permission failures during a save.

---

I do have few questions in mind.

1. Where will the user be created by calling create user API in graph ? Is it in Azure AD or somewhere else ?
2. I tried calling create user api by passing json and required headers, below is the error I get

[image]

3. Where exactly do I need to set the permission, I have already added permissions in the Application Registration Portal

[image]

But when API is executed it shows that I don't have enough permission.

FYI, I have registered the app using the same email id that I am using to test the APIs here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#

If I am not the admin, where exactly do I need to set or request for it ?

Comment: Remove the Authorization header in graph explorer, it should add it for you if you sign in

Comment: Do you choose `Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All` in the `modify permissions` in the left of the MS graph explorer? Also, as juunas said, if you login in, you dont need to add Authorization in the header.

Comment: Tried, with header and with out header but no luck, and Yes I have one more doubt here, when I tried to modify permissions and select Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All it says  **You have selected permissions that only an administrator can grant. To get access, an administrator can grant access to your entire organization.** So, I believe it is something to do with permissions.

Answer (score 7):

In order to [create a User](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_users) via Microsoft Graph, you need to request either `Directory.ReadWrite.All` or `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission.

***Important***: `Directory.ReadWrite.All` and  `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` both require Admin Consent before you can use them. If you're using Graph Explorer then the URI you need to provide your tenant Admin will be generated for you. If you're doing this in your own application, you'll need to construct an Admin Consent URI yourself. You can find more details on this at [v2 Endpoint & Admin Consent](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/).

Once you have the proper permissions configured (and consented), you'll want to `POST` the following JSON body/payload to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`:

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "displayName-value",
  "mailNickname": "mailNickname-value",
  "userPrincipalName": "upn-value@tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "password-value"
  }
}
```

This will create a user with a temporary password. The user will be asked to set a new password as after as they authenticate for the first time.

Comment: After assigning the right in the portal I needed to hit "grant admin consent" (or something) before it worked before it worked.

Answer (score 0):

> Where will the user be created by calling create user API in graph ?
>   Is it in Azure AD or somewhere else ?

Yes, the user created is in the Azure AD.

> I tried calling create user api by passing json and required headers,
>   below is the error I get

For your error, have you added the request body like the following, and this required admin:

[image]
[image]

> Where exactly do I need to set the permission, I have already added
>   permissions in the Application Registration Portal

The required permissions to create application:

[image]
For the details, please read [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_post_applications).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried but didn't work. Also I believe since I am not able to set **Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.Al** permissions by clicking on modify permissions, it says **You have selected permissions that only an administrator can grant. To get access, an administrator can grant access to your entire organization.** So, I believe it is something to do with permissions.

Comment: "to get access, an administrator can grant access to your entire organization." Login with exchange admin account