# How to create users using Microsoft Graph API (from Graph explorer and Java application)

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am new to Microsoft Graph API. I have read many articles on the web to understand  the usage of Microosft Garph API for managing users in Azure AD. I am creating a Springboot based REST API service, which needs to create users in Azure AD.

I have registered my application in Azure Active Directory. I have also 'Directory.ReadWrite.All" permission for Microsoft Graph API. I wanted to first try to create the user from Microsoft Garph explorer. In the Graph Explorer, I have to give authorization token in the Request header. In order to create authorization token, I have followed the instruction given in the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user. I have created the following URL based on the instruction, for obtaining Access token.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{mytenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=validclientID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:4200&response_mode=query&scope=Directory.ReadWrite.All&state=12345
```

When the above URL is accessed from the web browser, I get a message which says "Need Admin Approval". I am not the admin of the Azure AD and I do not have access to the admin of my client, so I am really stuck. Can anybody help me understand whether I will have to get admin consent each time I need to access "create user" functionality of Azure AD through MS Graph API? . I would also also need the create user functionaltiy in the Springboot API. In this case, how would Admin Consent work?. Is there anyway that the create user functionality can work without Admin consent.

I have read the following two questions in SO before posting this question

[How can I find the Admin Consent URL for an Azure AD App that requires Microsoft Graph "Read directory data" permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53309253/how-can-i-find-the-admin-consent-url-for-an-azure-ad-app-that-requires-microsoft)

[Create user using Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091590/create-user-using-microsoft-graph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want to create a user in your tenant , you can follow the steps below :

1. Create a new Azure AD app in your tenant, ask your tenant admin to grant "Directory.ReadWrite.All" permission to this app : 
   [image]
2. Create a app secret for your Azure AD app :
   [image]
   Use this secret and this Azure AD app ID to get access_token to call Microsoft Graph API :

   **Request URL :**

   POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<-your tenant name->/oauth2/v2.0/token

   **Request Header :**

   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

   **Request Body:**

> grant_type:client_credentials
>
> client_id:your client Id
>
> client_secret: Your application secret
>
> scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

You will get an access_token from this API calling.

See the screen shot below:

[image]
 3. Using the access_token we just created to call Microsoft Graph API to create a user :

[image]

As you can see , a user has been created :

[image]

If you have any further concerns , pls feel free to let me know : )

Comment: I created a POST request using Postman, but I am getting error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.   I have given all the values in the request body as per what you have suggested

Comment: Yes, provide this `grant_type=client_credentials`. I have updated the answer see once more please. Let me know if you have any more concern.

Comment: I confirm that I have given the grant_type in the request body in Postman. I do not understand why I am getting this error when grant_type is present in the request body.

Comment: It worked, when I gave grant_type as the first key in the Body. Strange!. I will update you after I have tried the other steps.

Comment: Yes , Its the format, You have to follow it as it is. I have also update the answer for your understanding with the screen shot.

Comment: Big thanks to you!. I am able to create the user now.  !

Comment: @KurioZ7 Glad to hear. Thanks and happy coding.

Comment: I am getting 401 forbidden issue if I use access token of default scope.

Comment: Please share your issue in different question in order to get specific solution, because I haven't seen your issue yet, so need more details and I cannot modify this answer based on your issue. So need new question with problem details. Hope I have explained to your clearly, why I cannot assist you here.