# Is it possible to call Ms Graph API from an Azure AD B2C app using local accounts?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal-react

I have created an App under Azure B2C tenant.

The app is using a custom sign-in/sign-up policy to log in to local users.

However, my app has an admin view, where I would want the log-in users to be able to create accounts for whoever needs access within the app. I have seen that this is possible using Azure Ms Graph API.

However, I keep getting an `InvalidAuthenticationToken` Error, when I try to call Ms Graph API.

```
 error:
    code: "InvalidAuthenticationToken"
    innerError: {date: "2021-08-11T14:25:09", request-id: "8a49ae82-a669-4bb4-af6e-b698e095dadc", client-request-id: "8a49ae82-a669-4bb4-af6e-b698e095dadc"}
    message: "Invalid x5t claim."
```

I couldn't find any solution online. Is this even possible? And if there's a way around it, how can I do it?

Thank you!.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

A user's B2C authentication cannot be used to authorize to AAD protected apps, or Microsoft APIs (which are also protected by AAD). As such, when you use MSAL.js, you cannot use the <your-tenant>.b2clogin.com/.../token endpoint to obtain a token for MS Graph API.

Source: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/working-with-b2c.md

Comment: What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you went into more detail on your use case.

You have a B2C local account and you want to create users in AAD or in B2C?

If in B2C, yes you can do this as per this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations).

If in AAD, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003660/how-to-create-users-using-microsoft-graph-api-from-graph-explorer-and-java-appl).

Make sure that your application has the correct permissions.

Comment: Thank you @rbrayb . I have a B2C account, and I want to create users in B2C account. The local users sign up using userflows.

From the article. They stated that **Delegated permissions for users signing in through user flows or custom policies cannot be used against delegated permissions for Microsoft Graph.**

Comment: Agreed but if you look at the B2C article e.g. you see it mentions a secret key. This is because it is not using the authorisation code grant but rather the client credentials grant that operates in the context of the application, not the user.