# How to change from single tenant to multiple tenant in azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

Originally when I setup my application in azure AD at work I selected single tenant. However, I actually need to use multi tenant (AzureADMultipleOrgs). When you try to change to multiple tenant in the UI in azure AD portal you get this message :

"Due to temporary differences in supported functionality, we don't recommend enabling personal Microsoft accounts for an existing registration. If you need to enable personal accounts, you can do so using the manifest editor.  Learn more about these restrictions.​"

Then if you go to learn more about this it states you should be using the manifest to change this. So I change the value of "signInAudience" to AzureADMultipleOrgs and still when I go to sign in it is still askign me to use an email address for the single tenant (email address from that tenant domain). I thought changing this value would allow me to use any work or school/organization email address to sign in but nothing has changed. Am I doing something wrong because MS does not give much help to switch from single to multiple.

Comment: If you followed @SrideviMachavarapu-MT solution to convert to `common` and it still doesn't work, you may take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70271796/15581227).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***In order to change your application "Supported account type" from `Single-Tenant` to `multi-Tenant`, please check the following:***

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your app -> Authentication*

[image]

If you are using code to sign-in, make sure to change the below settings:

```cs
Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
Audience = "api://Your_App_ID";// Your Application ID URI
```

Please check this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant) that can help you in the process.

> Due to temporary differences in supported functionality, we don't
> recommend enabling personal Microsoft accounts for an existing
> registration. If you need to enable personal accounts, you can do so
> using the manifest editor. Learn more about these restrictions

Please **note** that, after registering the application if you want to change the **supported type to Personal Microsoft accounts**, you cannot find that option and will get the above warning.

[image]

So, it suggests you to change it in Manifest. You can ignore that WARNING, if you are changing to **multi-tenant**.

**If still the issue persists, please check the below references:**

[How to: Change the account types supported by an application - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-modify-supported-accounts#why-changing-to-multi-tenant-can-fail)

[Validation differences by supported account types - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/supported-accounts-validation)

[azure-docs/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant.md)

Comment: For Audience is that Application (client) ID in Azure Portal because in my appsetting.json file i set the ClientID already. under the ClientId tag.

Comment: The steps you listed unfortunately did not fix my issue. When I get to the sign in page it still says use format user@cloud.domain.com and if I try my email it says account not found . I am thinking based off those links you listed i needed to register my app in the tenant of my company that has the tenant domain which matches our email domains and not the cloud.domain.com. I dont have access to that tenant though.